# How do I configure a bandpass filter?

Tags: audio, web-audio-api

I'm trying to use the Web Audio API's bandpass filter functionality, but I believe my question is more general. I don't understand the "Q" value of the bandpass filter. I would like to be able to configure the filter to pass frequencies that are within Y hertz of a middle frequency X hertz.

I'm very new to audio programming, so are there other variables I need to consider to compute Q?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's say you have a filter at 1000Hz, and you want it to start at 500Hz and end at 2000Hz.

First off, you'll notice it doesn't extend the same number of hertz in each direction. That's because filter bandwidth is based on octaves, not frequencies. So in this case, it extends one octave down and one octave up. Put another way, the frequency was divided by 2 on the low end and multiplied by 2 on the high end - which gives it a bandwidth of 2 octaves.

Anyway, here's how you can calculate it, assuming you know the frequencies:

`Q = center_frequency / (top_frequency - bottom_frequency)`

Which in this case would be `1000 / ( 2000 - 500 )`, or 0.667.

You can also calculate it without knowing the top and bottom frequencies as long as you have a target bandwidth (in octaves) in mind:

```
function getQ( bandwidth ){
  return Math.sqrt( Math.pow(2, bandwidth) ) / ( Math.pow(2, bandwidth) - 1 )
}
```

Again, if you pass `2` as the bandwidth argument, you'll get the same result: Q = 0.667.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. I'm amazed that I haven't been able to find a nice simple explanation like that online.

Comment: So, am I correct in thinking that in terms of frequencies, rather than octaves, the "middle frequency" is always a third of the way through the band?

Comment: A filter at 1000Hz with a bandwidth of 1/3 octave would have a lower frequency of 897Hz and a higher frequency of 1121Hz (there are tables where you can look these up). Anyway, 1000 isn't 1/3 between 897 and 1121. The 1/3 thing only works out when the bandwidth is 2 octaves.

Comment: So it sounds like if I want to pull out specific bands of frequencies, it would be easiest for me to use a low pass and high pass filter in sequence.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. By the way, this might help: http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-cutoffFrequencies.htm

Comment: Or, to visualize the Web Audio filtering, http://webaudio-io2012.appspot.com/frames/frequency-response.html.