# Bandpass filter, which frequency and Q value to represent frequency range?

Tags: javascript, audio, filtering, web-audio-api

I want to use a Web Audio bandpass filter to emphasise the frequencies from 300Hz to 3kHz.

However the [bandpass filter in the Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BiquadFilterNode) has only one frequency value (representing the center) and one [Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627013/how-do-i-configure-a-bandpass-filter) value (representing octaves?).

How to set them correctly to represent my `to` and `from` frequeuncy range?

Comment: I tried to streamline the question a bit (because of the close votes). Is there something more I could do? Which parts are "to broad"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var from = 300;
var to = 30000;
var geometricMean = Math.sqrt(from * to);

var filter = audioContext.createBiquadFilter();
filter.type = 'bandpass';
filter.frequency.value = geometricMean;
filter.Q.value = geometricMean / (to - from);
```

It seems like the frequency is the [geometric mean](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-geommean.htm) of the `from` and `to` value. With this value as center frequency I am now able to [calculate the Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627013/how-do-i-configure-a-bandpass-filter) value.

Comment: You can do that; you can also use a chained highshelf and lowshelf filter to do this.